# Unusual error message defining a second static member function?

Tags: c++, class, methods, member-functions

I've run into this very simple issue where I'm getting this error message:

> member function may not be redeclared outside its class when trying to define body

Others here have had it before, but it's mostly been an actual redeclaration of a member function (i.e. writing `int ClassName::methodName()` when they were meant to write `int something = ClassName::methodName()`) but oddly enough that's not what my problem is.

My problem is this:

```
//avr_helper.h
#pragma once
#include <avr/io.h>
enum input_type {INPUT, OUTPUT};
enum write_type {HIGH, LOW};

class register_b
{
    static void assign(long register_pin, input_type type);
    static void write(long pin, write_type type);
}

//avr_helper.cpp
#include "avr_helper.h"
void register_b::assign(long register_pin, input_type type) { // this works fine
    switch(type) {
    case INPUT:
        DDRB &= ~(1<<register_pin);
        break;
    case OUTPUT:
        DDRB |= (1<<register_pin);
        break;
}

void register_b::write(long pin, write_type type) { // this gives the error mentioned in the title
    switch(type) {
    case HIGH:
        PORTB &= ~(1<<pin);
        break;
    case LOW:
        PORTB |= (1<<pin);
        break;
    }
```

Defining member functions has never failed me before, so why do I get the error now?

Comment: You are missing a brace } at the end of register_b::write() and register_b::assign(), probably because the switch statement looks like it has ended the function - a simple mistake but is easily made and can make things very ugly

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a close curly brace on the `switch` statement in the `assign` member function definition. I think this is tripping up the parser, hence the error. You can see this here:

```
void register_b::assign(long register_pin, input_type type) { // this works fine
    switch(type) {
    case INPUT:
        DDRB &= ~(1<<register_pin);
        break;
    case OUTPUT:
        DDRB |= (1<<register_pin);
        break;
    // <-- Missing } here?
}
```

Try adding the `}` back in.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I can't believe I made that rookie mistake... and without even noticing too

Comment: Good catch. ;) The same error seems to be in the other method.

Comment: No worries - we all make mistakes like this!

Comment: It triggered a bizarre and counterintuitive error message that had nothing to do with the root cause of the problem. Sounds SO-worthy to me. :-)